# Synthesize acyl chloride from aldehyde

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis

I know it is usually easier to go from an acyl chloride to an aldehyde,

but is there a way to synthesize acyl chlorides from an aldehyde?

**Edit:**

Upon some textbook reading ([Wiley: Organic Chemistry 11th Ed, Solomons](http://ca.wiley.com/WileyCDA/WileyTitle/productCd-EHEP002536.html)), I realized that aldehydes could also be oxidized to carboxylic acids with chromic acid in aqueous acetone (the [Jones Oxidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jones_oxidation)) and then you could react the carboxylic acid with thionyl chloride or phosphorus trichloride to yield the acyl chloride.

Another method was to convert the aldehyde into a [cyanohydrin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyanohydrin) and through hydrolysis the -CN group could be then converted into $\ce{RCOOH}$. Then react $\ce{RCOOH}$ with $\ce{SOCl2}$ to get the acyl chloride.

Comment: If what you want is to convert RCHO to RCOCl, then I think your cyanohydrin method won't quite work.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to affect the transformation, as you have realised, and many of which Loong has detailed below in his post.

This answer gives one method which I would be confident of working practically, in the lab, using common reagents. A full search of Reaxys of SciFinder would reveal conditions/methods more suitable for a specific aldehyde.

A [Pinnick oxidation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pinnick_oxidation) will convert an aldehyde into its corresponding carboxylic acid, which may then be treated with a reagent such as [oxalyl chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxalyl_chloride#Synthesis_of_acyl_chlorides) to give the desired acyl chloride.

[image]

Answer (score 11):

In some cases, the direct reaction with chlorine is possible:

[image: 2-chlorobenzaldehyde and dichlorine to 2-chlorobenzoyl chloride]
[Clarke, H. T.; Taylor, E. R. *o*-Chlorobenzoyl chloride. *Org. Synth.* **1929,** *Vol. 9,* 34; **1941,** *Coll. Vol. 1,* 155.](http://dx.doi.org/10.15227/orgsyn.009.0034)

In other reactions, radical chlorinating agents are used:

[image: aldehyde and tert-butyl hypochlorite to acyl chloride]
[Ginsburg, D. The Action of *t*-Butyl Hypochlorite on Organic Compounds. II. Aromatic Aldehydes. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1951,** *73* (2), 702–704.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01146a061)

[image: aldehyde and N-chlorosuccinimide to acyl chloride]
Hebbelynck, M. F.; Martin, R. H. *Bull. Soc. Chim. Belg.* **1951,** *60,* 54.

[image: aldehyde and sulfuryl chloride to acyl chloride]
Arai, M. *Bull. Chem. Soc. Jpn.* **1962,** *35,* 1272; **1964,** *37,* 1280; **1965,** *38,* 252.

[image: aldehyde and sulfuryl chloride to acyl chloride]
[Winstein, S.; Seubold, F. H. Jr. Free radical reactions of aldehydes. *J. Am. Chem. Soc.* **1947,** *69* (11), 2916–2917.](http://dx.doi.org/10.1021/ja01203a513)